# How to pass data from a function in react native component

Tags: function, react-native, django-rest-framework, react-functional-component

I have created a Banner Component in React Native and now im trying to add data from a function (seperate .js file) in this component. I want to fetch the data on the inital load from my Home Screen but i dont know how to pass the data from my function. I hope you can help me.

This is my code:

home.js

```
export function HomeScreen() {

    {/*This will cause an error*/}
    const [item, setItem] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
    {/*Function where i fetch my Data from API */}
        getbannerdata().then(res => {
            setItem(res)
        })
        console.log(item)
    }, [])


    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
                <View>
                    {/*Banner Component with Data param*/}
                    <Banner data={item} /> 
                    <Text>Home</Text>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

My function:
bannerdata.js

```
export const getbannerdata = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
    console.log('Test')
    fetch('http://192.168.178.46:8000/intranet/messages/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setData(res)


        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
        return data;
};
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `useState` in your component only not in the function where you fetch data.

bannerdata.js

```
export const getbannerdata = () => {
    return fetch('http://192.168.178.46:8000/intranet/messages/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
};
```

home.js

```
import { getbannerdata } from './bannerdata'; //import getbannerdata function and you should provide the path of bannerdata.js

export function HomeScreen() {

    const [item, setItem] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
    {/*Function where i fetch my Data from API */}
        getbannerdata()
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setItem(res);
        });
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, []);


    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
                <View>
                    {/*Banner Component with Data param*/}
                    <Banner data={item} /> 
                    <Text>Home</Text>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
This is my final solution.
Its a little bit different but now it works as expected

bannerdata.js

```
import * as React from 'react';

function getbannerdata(){
    return fetch ('http://192.168.178.46:8000/intranet/messages/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((resData) => {
            return resData;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

};

export { getbannerdata }
```

home.js

```
import {getbannerdata} from './home/bannerdata.js';

export function HomeScreen() {

    const [item, setItem] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getbannerdata()
        .then(res => setItem(res))
    }, []);


    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
                <View>
                    {/*Banner Component with Data param*/}
                    <Banner data={item} /> 
                    <Text>Home</Text>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```